# Wildfly 20 fails to run "out-of-the-box" on Ubuntu 20

Tags: java, crash, wildfly

Immediately after installing Wildfly 20 on a fresh Ubuntu 20 system my 1st attempt to run Wildfly crashes with a "Could not create server data directory: /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/standalone/data" error. Here is the full dump:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

Failed to read or configure the org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:117)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:336)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:289)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:298)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:546)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:97)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:170)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:132)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:445)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:394)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:382)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:430)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:457)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:115)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/standalone/log/server.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:151)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.setFile(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:104)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:189)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:119)
    at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.15.Final//org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.<init>(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:72)
    ... 18 more
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYSRV0124: Could not create server data directory: /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/standalone/data
    at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.<init>(ServerEnvironment.java:463)
    at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:388)
    at org.jboss.as.server@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:96)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:352)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:320)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:617)
```

Here are the installation steps from https://docs.wildfly.org/20/Getting_Started_Guide.html#installation:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk

sudo apt-get update

Version_Number=20.0.1.Final

wget https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/$Version_Number/wildfly-$Version_Number.tar.gz -P /tmp

sudo tar xf /tmp/wildfly-$Version_Number.tar.gz -C /opt/

cd /opt/wildfly-$Version_Number/bin

./standalone.sh
```

Can anyone explain what has gone wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildfly doesn't have permission to write to `/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/standalone/log/server.log` because you extracted it with `sudo` so the directories and files are all owned by root.

If this is running in a development type environment, run:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final
```

This will change all files and directories to be owned by you.  If, instead, you run as a generic user (say wildfly) just change to:

```
sudo chown -R wildfly /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final
```

Comment: Hi stdunbar,

Thanks for your suggestion to change the Owner.  (Note that I had to use sudo or I couldn't install into /opt).

I followed your suggestion and changed ownership to my (Admin) user and I now am able to start Wildfly as a service! So again, thanks for your suggestion.

However, now I have a problem with the service setting up some critical paths.

... CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: When I install (in a different VM) Wildfly in /home/myuser/ instead of /opt and *NOT* as a service and run it with the following, I am able to use "Test Connection" to connect to a Sybase SQL Anywhere database using the sajdbc4 driver.
cd ~/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myuser/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main
export CLASSPATH=.:/home/myuser/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar
./standalone.sh

... CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: On the other hand, when I setup a new VM exactly the same way except for installing into /opt and the extra steps to run Wildfly as a service my "Test Connection" fails with:
2020-08-28 13:13:41,341 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.sajdbc4_jar (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/TestDB, service org.wildfly.data-source.TestDB] 
... CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: I can run a simple Java test app on this system that connects and dumps a database table with:
cd $HOME/Desktop
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main
export CLASSPATH=.:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar
java sajdbc4DriverTest.java

Note that the launch of the service uses the same paths.

So, my question is do you have any idea as to why Wildfly is ignoring the two paths I set prior to starting the service?

Thanks again very much.
... CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT

Comment: I'd strongly request that you accept this answer and open a new question as they are very different questions.  I believe I can help with that one too but it's very difficult to read the new question in just comments.