# Why am I getting an error when trying to run WildFLy on Intellij?Application Server was not connected before run configuration

Tags: rest, maven, intellij-idea, jax-rs, wildfly-16

I'm creating a Wildfly + Maven Restful API in Intellij, everything seems fine except at run time the program crashes saying "Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop,Unable to ping server at localhost:8080". I'm following a tutorial step by step at https://courses.bekwam.net/public_tutorials/bkcourse_wildfly_restful_devenv.html. So the problem is probably with WildFly. Please give me a detailed guide on how to sort this.

Here's my code:
package com.example;

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class Api extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add( HelloWorld.class );
        return set;
    }

}
```

```
package com.example;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage() { return "Hello, World! 3"; }
}
```

POM.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PracticeProj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

[image: This is the error im getting in the output]

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/63624519/104891 help?

Comment: Please do not post images of errors. Instead copy and paste them here. This helps searchability and makes it easier for people to copy the errors so they can help you search for solutions.